# code snippet for vc++[code snippet manager]?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, code-snippets

Where can I get a code snippets for VC++ that can be used with the code snippet manager in Visual Studio 2008?

I have SnippetEditor installed how to create snippet for **VC++**.

Comment: Isn't cut & paste programming supposed to be a "code smell"?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth check out this video abt code snippet http://beta.channel9.msdn.com/posts/PDC2005ShowOff/GotCodeSnippetsNET-The-Repository-for-Visual-Studio-Code-Snippets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is not possible in VS2008 without
>   using 3rd party software. However it
>   is possible in VS2005 with the "Power
>   Pack installer". See [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/015e6988-f9b1-4a7c-b543-d464267f5a54/)
>   for details.

So your options are to either revert to VS2005, or use a 3rd party snippet tool such as the already suggested [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/). I would go with the latter.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend Visual Assist X, as it's having built-in snippet manager plus tons of other features as well.

[Whole Tomato](http://www.wholetomato.com)

Comment: Yup. I can't live without it, especially when doing C++.

Answer (score 0):

The video you are referring to is about http://gotcodesnippets.net/. The site only contains snippets for managed code though.